# Why Do i get null value in angularjs variable after http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using Angularjs as frontend 
I have defined the variable `ttest` defined before `$http` call.
after that i assign data to this variable .

the value `ttest[0]` has value in `$http` function but outside there is no value available there

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$http,$log) {
    var imagePath = 'img/list/60.jpeg';

  var ttest=[];
var url = "https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php";

$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        ttest = response.data;
  $scope.messages =ttest
  $log.info(ttest[0]);

    });

  $log.info(ttest[0]);


  });
```

Comment: what does the response contains ?

Comment: because `$http` is asynchronous

Comment: try creating `ttest` as a variable on scope

Comment: Your code is correct can you add a console.log(response) in then function and tell me what you getting in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Check the below comment ,you will find out what are you doing wrong 
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$http,$log) {
    var imagePath = 'img/list/60.jpeg';

  var ttest=[];
var url = "https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php";

$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
  //      ttest = response.data;
        ttest = response.records; <-- change data to records
  $scope.messages =ttest
  $log.info(ttest[0]);

    });

  $log.info(ttest[0]);


  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request you're making is asynchronous that means it is non blocking. So before your request is sent, the code below it executes. Do something like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$http,$log) {
    var imagePath = 'img/list/60.jpeg';

  var ttest=[];
var url = "https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php";

$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        ttest = response.data;
  $scope.messages =ttest
  $log.info(ttest[0]);

$scope.yourCallback(); // do whatever you want to do here in this function

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript scope of variable is functional. Since `then` is call back function , `ttest` wont be available outside of the scope.

You can create the function outside of the scope which updates `ttest` variable and call it from the then callback function.